# LDAP: How to add a new user to a group inside an OU

Tags: active-directory, ldap, directoryentry

I have some code using `DirectoryEntry` to manipulate the local Active Directory via LDAP. Currently I find a specific `OU`, add a user to it, update the properties of the user and then commit all changes:

```
DirectoryEntry ldapRoot = new DirectoryEntry(ldapString, user, password);
DirectoryEntry userGroup = ldapRoot.Children.Find("OU=OUGroup");
DirectoryEntry newUser = userGroup.Children.Add("CN=" + userName, "user");
newUser.Properties["displayName"].Value = displayName;

...

newUser.CommitChanges();
userGroup.Close();
ldapRoot.Close();
```

ldapString is something akin to `LDAP:\\DC=company,DC=local`, basically it's just fetching the root entry.

I change several Properties, but it's all working fine. However, I have another `OU` called SharePoint_Groups, which has a group inside called `Internal`. I want to add the new user as a member of this group, but I'm at a loss of how to do it. I tried the following:

```
DirectoryEntry spGroup = ldapRoot.Children.Find("OU=Sharepoint_Groups");
DirectoryEntry internal = spGroup.Children.Find("CN=Internal");
```

It does not work and I am not sure how I should address `Internal` - is CN= correct or should I use some other specification?

And, once I have the correct group, how do I add the existing user to it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, to add a user to an existing group, you need to bind to that group and update it's `member` property, using the user's fully qualified distinguished name:

```
DirectoryEntry deGroup = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Internal,OU=Sharepoint_Groups,DC=Company,DC=local");

string userDN = newUser.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();

deGroup.Properties["member"].Add(userDN);
deGroup.CommitChanges();
```

A great resource for stuff like this is the CodeProject article [How to do just about everything in Active Directory using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx) - lots of useful code samples!

Comment: Worked perfectly, seems it error'd out when doing the Add() because I was using just "CN=username" instead of the full DN. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why this works locally but throws "Access is denied" when moved to the IIS server?

Comment: @PlatypusMaximus: sounds like permissions - locally, this code runs in the context of your own user - on the web, most likely under the context of the app pool user of IIS